# Syntax error:MySQL Insert Select

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-select

I have this query to insert into tbl_userprofile:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_userprofile (userId, name, surname, gender, nationality, address,  mobile, department, email, question, answer)
SELECT tbl_user.Id , '$name', '$surname', '$gender', '$nationality', '$address','$mobile',  '$department', '$email', '$question', '$answer'
FROM tbl_user
WHERE username = '$uname'";
```

I'm getting a syntax error saying: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pet-peeve', 'dirt' FROM tbl_user WHERE username = 'alex'' at line 2"

NOTE: pet-peeve and dirt are the question and answer.
I dont know how i'm getting a syntax error. Please where is my syntax error? Thanks

Comment: try to code your inser statement with explicit values to have a test and run it from a mysql query client.

Comment: I can't see any error on your syntax except for the statement to be vulnerable with sql injection. Can you please echo your query before executing it on the database?

Comment: There might be some plain text in those two last field so maybe there are quote around, better to use [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to your `$question` and `$answer` variables

Comment: I believe the problem would lie with the $email field seeing as $question and $answer both look ok, but yes, other than that, everything here.

Comment: @Fabio thats right. It worked after using addslashes() on the variables. Thanks

Comment: @dhani You welcome, i just added answer so people in the future could know what is the correct fix and be helped, don't forget to accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some plain text in those two last field so maybe there are quote around, better to use `addslashes()` to your `$question` and `$answer` variables

```
'$email', '".addslashes($question)."', '".addslashes($answer)."' FROM tbl_user
```